# How to use less cpu?

Tags: python, selenium, cpu, cpu-usage, pythonanywhere

I wrote a bot to accept follow requests immediately.
and I tried to upload it to pythonanywhere so it can work 24/7, and with the free plan you're only allowed 100s of 100% CPU usage per day, after that they put you in what they call a tarpit where you use much less cpu if any.

the issue with the bot is that it requires refreshing chrome to check for new requests, and that eats all the cpu in a matter of seconds, and hardly keeps running after that.
[image]

here's the portion of the code that i mean:

```
while True:
        try:
            confirm_buttons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[text()='Confirm']")
            for confirm_button in confirm_buttons:
                confirm_button.click()
                sleep(5)
                print('found')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('none')
            browser.refresh()
            print('refreshed')
            sleep(5)
        finally:
            browser.refresh()
            print("refreshing")
            sleep(5)
```

I'm using selenium with Chrome, and pyvirtualdisplay since i can't use headless browser.
**Please tell me if there's any way i can minimize the cpu usage, or if there's a better way to do it**

answer here or dm @*poortxbyy* in ig if you can help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with the method you're trying to implement. Namely:

1. You're using Selenium. In other words, you've are simulating a web browser—which is an expensive process as it is—and you're expecting to host it online for free.
2. Constant monitoring. I.e. you're continously updating the Selenium browser, which means you're repeatedly overloading point number 1.

An obvious solution to this would be to reduce the number of updates per unit time. Period.

Another solution might be to scrap the infinite loop altogether and build the bot so that it knows *when* to update. I can think of multiple ways to do this, but the point is: you have to find a way for the bot to know you have a new follower without having to use Selenium, and only using Selenium to click the buttons. Perhaps by extracting the site's HTML only and interacting with a string to quickly (and cheaply) retrieve information from it.
Or even better, depending on what social media you're interacting with, using their API to retrieve information on new followers. On top of that, the API might even allow you to accept the request in and of itself. It comes down to reading the documentation and finding out what your options are. Some APIs may let you set up webhooks so that your bot may sleep until you get a new follower. A quick look into [Twitter's API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api) and [Instagram's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) Graph API seem promising.
In other words, browser automation often feels like the most obvious solution, but more often it isn't. You have to find a way to interact more directly with the data available to you.

Also, let's not forget that social media sites may detect the unusual behavour and block your account to protect it.

Comment: Thanks, i'm new tp python, so if possible, please explain me how can i use something else to detect new requests and possibly accept them. also, instagram, which is the SM i'm using, doesn't offer and API as far as i know.

Comment: @OussamaDarrazi, Instagram does offer multiple APIs for those that need it. [Check this out](https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/apis/). Though I'm pretty positive it won't let you accept any follower requests, considering how unusual it is for business accounts to be private. Again, you should read the documentation. Using the API is really your only viable solution, since otherwise you'll be forced to login to retrieve information from your private account (forcing you to use browser automation).

Comment: Yea you're right, you can't retrieve or accept follow requests with the api, so it won't do the job for me. But you said something about multiple ways to do it, including the extracting the HTML or something. Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

There are few work around for it.

1. Simply increase the time for every refresh, it will not accept follow requests immediately but you can set time to update after every 2-3 min.
2. it depends on what you are using it for, use the API to do this work or at least check for any new request before accepting it.
3. I know using --headless is not an option for you but that might be the only other option, so take a look at that.

Comment: Using --headless is explicitly mentioned as being not an option.

Comment: @Mast yeah i know but it might be the only option left.

Comment: Thanks, increasing the time is simply not an option, since i'm challenge to accept in less than 5s. And, instagram doesn't offer an API as far as i know, and i couldn't think of a way to check for requests other than refreshing and checking with selenium. let me know if you can think of any.

Comment: @OussamaDarrazi Use GCP its free for 1 year and there is a "always free tier" option that will be more than enough to meet your needs